# AngularJS checkbox & ng-change works very strange

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with items like:

```
{ 
   key : 'abc',
   color: 'Red',
   show: true
}

<div ng-repeat="x in myArray">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x" ng-change="changeShow($index)" checked="checked" />
    <div style="background-color:{{x.color}}; width: 5px;" class="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <label>{{x.key}}</label>
    {{x}}
</div>

$scope.changeShow = function (index) {
    $scope.myArray[index].show = !$scope.myArray[index].show;
}
```

the problem is, when I click on any chekcbox, the `{{x}}` renders only `true`/ `false`, and the `color` and `name` disappears. Why ??

Comment: You should bind x.show to your checkbox instead of x

Comment: Would it be possible to set up a Plunkr/FiddleJS snippet with the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bind your check box to x.show instead x
2. You can remove `ng-change="changeShow"` bit as angular will update show properties

Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('homeCtrl', homeCtrl);

homeCtrl.inject = ['$scope']

function homeCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.myArray = [{
    key: 'abc',
    color: 'Red',
    show: true
  }]


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in myArray">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.show" checked="checked" />
    <div style="background-color:{{x.color}}; width: 5px;" class="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <label>{{x.key}}</label>
    {{x}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind x.show to ng-checked and change `ng-change` to `ng-click` if all you want to do is flop the value of show.  You don't need ng-model.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="x.show" ng-click="changeShow($index)" />
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QzLzTrmmSNsCB24tpfN3?p=preview)